# Linq Sort by 2 Columns (Created and Modified) whichever is greater

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I have an `IQueryable` by the name **query** and need to return a list of results sorted by the last modified date.

The entity has two columns called CreatedOn and ModifiedOn. CreatedOn is not nullable and is set when a new entity is created. The other column ModifiedOn is set only when the entity has been modified.

Last modified date here means to sort by either CreatedOn or ModifiedOn whichever is greater.

The below code does not work with the MongoDB C# driver.

```
query = query.OrderBy(e => e.ModifiedOn == null ? e.CreatedOn : e.ModifiedOn);
```

It throws a `NotSupportedException`

> "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: ."

I am aware of why it throws the NotSupportedException. I am looking for a solution to sort the entities. Is there any other way in which I can achieve the desired result?

The solution should work on an IQueryable and not on an IEnumerable in memory as the no. of entities can be vary large.

Comment: Is it a problem if you do it once you have the list ion memory?

Comment: @PaoloCosta: The list is very large and I cannot afford to do the sort in memory.

Answer (score 2):

In c# 8 and postgresql this work:

```
query = query.OrderBy(e => e.LastModified ?? e.Created);
```